# function is not define when pass the data to php file, what is the error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is my javaScript code. when i want to pass the value from the text field and text area to another php file for update the database.

```
function updatetask() {

    var tid = document.getElementById('task_id').value;
    var pid = document.getElementById('projct_id').value;
    var title = document.getElementById('task').value;
    var desc = document.getElementById('description').value;
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag').value;
    var sdate = document.getElementById('sdate').value;
    var edate = document.getElementById('edate').value;
    var status = document.getElementById('status_option').value;
    var completed = document.getElementById('complete').value;     
    var uid = document.getElementById('assign_id').value;   

    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: '<?php echo $url; ?>/js-files/updateTitle.php', 
        data: { task_id: tid, proj_id: pid, task: title, descrip: desc, tag: tag, start: sdate, due: edate, state: status complete: completed, emp_id: uid },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success update assigners');  
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: better use `$('#task').value` instead of `document.getElementById('task').value`;

Comment: Where is it saying function is not defined in your javascript / html?

Comment: where do you call update function? if it's within a closure it may be a problem of scope

Comment: Use the browser's Developer Tool console! It will show you the error.

Comment: You might have missed one `comma` in between `state: status complete: completed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a comma after state: status